# Paperclip in Production with Unicorn: uninitialized constant Paperclip (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, paperclip, capistrano, unicorn

I added Paperclip to my app then tried to deploy to my VPS using capistrano.  The deploy happens successfully, but when I try to access my app on the VPS, I get the Rails Error Page.
There is no information in `production.log`, but `unicorn.log` has the following error:

```
E, [2013-06-25T19:44:07.372060 #21995] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Paperclip (NameError)
/home/deployer/apps/arcsite/releases/20130625182331/config/initializers/paperclip.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

The initializer file is `paperclip.rb` and has these contents:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :zone do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.zone_id
end
```

It's an interpolater to allow me to use the folder structure I want.

If I remove the `paperclip.rb` initializer file, I get an error that `has_attachment` is undefined in my class, making it seem like the `paperclip` gem isn't being properly loaded.

I tried to uninstall/reinstall the gem, but when I ran `gem uninstall paperclip`, it told me that the paperclip gem was not installed.  When I ran `bundle show paperclip` it did show a directory (I'm using RVM), so I manually installed the paperclip gem with `gem install paperclip`.  I'm still getting the same error.

This app works fine in development on the `thin` server.

My VPS setup:

- nginx
- unicorn
- rvm
- capistrano

rails version: 3.2.13
paperclip version: 3.4.2

I followed [Ryan's screencast to set up nginx/unicorn](http://railscasts.com/episodes/293-nginx-unicorn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was some weird installation behavior.  Had to work with the RVM people and have updated the rvm capistrano documentation to reflect the new procedures.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that unicorn wasn't recognizing my newly installed gems, all I had to do was simply manually stop and then manually start unicorn and everything got taken care of.  I had this exact same issue after deploying my app with paperclip installed.

In the application's root directory through SSH--

```
service unicorn_"app name" stop
```

followed by

```
service unicorn_"app name" start
```