# Rails 3.2.13 Production App Started Crashing After Adding ImageMagick and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, imagemagick, rmagick

I have a rails app in production and after I pushed changes to it that included ImageMagick and Paperclip, it started giving me a 500 error.  It runs beautifully on my local machine, and all my logs say are --

"Connecting to database specified by database.yml"

over and over and over again, so I'm not producing an error that gives me any kind of direction with where to start.

My production box is running Ubuntu 10.04.  Let me know if you need any more information as I'm sure there could be something else happening.  Like I said, the app runs fine on my local machine and everything works.  Everything was running fine on the production machine before I added the image uploading.

**================= UPDATE =================**

Just to fill in extra info, I have checked the installation of both the rmagick gem in the application on the production box and the installation of ImageMagick via "identify -version" on the production box and both are installed.

**================= ANOTHER UPDATE =================**

I started up the application in the production environment on my local machine and everything ran just fine... still won't pull up on my production server though

**================= YET ANOTHER UPDATE =================**

I found an identical problem and the question was "answered" but didn't actually provide any information as to how to solve it. Thoughts?

[Paperclip in Production with Unicorn: uninitialized constant Paperclip (NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306285/paperclip-in-production-with-unicorn-uninitialized-constant-paperclip-nameerro)

Comment: did you check imagemagick installation in your production server? Was it successful?

Also check the installation of rmagick gem.

Comment: I did check both the installation of the rmagick gem and the installation of imagemagick on the production box via "identify -version".  Both are installed.

Comment: any production logs with backtraces for 500 internal error?

Comment: @arun15thmay - nope, literally just line after line of "COnnecting to database specified by database.yml" - no actually 500 error, the rails app is just showing the page that says "We're sorry, but something went wrong." - you can see for yourself at 162.242.213.218

Comment: Are you able to log into ruby console on production server?

Comment: @Manish - when I try to run console on the production server it says "-bash: rails: command not found"

Comment: I had a similar situation - although not with imagemagick specifically - which was due to a syntax error in my application hence it wouldn't startup. Try running the application on your development system in production mode. Same effect?

Comment: @Kumala - I have tried running the app in the production environment on my development machine and everything runs just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that unicorn wasn't recognizing my newly installed gems, all I had to do was simply manually stop and then manually start unicorn and everything got taken care of.

In the application's root directory through SSH--

```
service unicorn_"app name" stop
```

followed by

```
service unicorn_"app name" start
```